# GLFW larger window than screen resolution

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, glfw

When rendering off-screen content with OpenGL I am trying to use a window larger than the current screen resolution. The following code fails to render correctly if so (it renders to a portion of the window), but works OK when the window size is <= the resolution. (Error checks and stuff removed).

```
void run(int wi2,int he2)
{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW_FALSE);
    win = glfwCreateWindow(wi2, he2, "OpenGL", 0, 0);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(win);
    hOpenGL = glfwGetWin32Window(win);
    ShowWindow(hOpenGL, SW_HIDE);
    if (!loadExtensions())
    {
       ....
    }
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Use the Z buffer
    glfwSwapInterval(0); // Do not wait for screen refresh between frames
    glfwSetWindowSize(win, wi2,he2);
    glViewport(0, 0, wi2,he2);
    SetEvent(hRun2);
    MSG msg;
    for (;;)
    {
        HANDLE he[2] = { hRun1,hRunE };
        auto gc = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(2, he, 0, INFINITE, QS_ALLEVENTS);
        if (gc == WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1)
        {
            // end
            glfwDestroyWindow(win);
            win = 0;
            break;
        }
        else
        if (gc == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
        {
            // render
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            glClearColor(runc.bg.r, runc.bg.g, runc.bg.b, runc.bg.a);

            // Load uniforms, others are omitted for simplicity
            float wh[4] = { wi2,he2,0,0 };
            auto uloc =
                glGetUniformLocation(runc.prg, "iResolution");
            glUniform3fv(uloc, 1, wh);
            glLoadIdentity();

            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            glVertex2i(-wi2 / 2, -he2 / 2);
            glVertex2i(wi2 / 2, -he2 / 2);
            glVertex2i(wi2 / 2, he2 / 2);
            glVertex2i(-wi2 / 2, he2 / 2);
            glEnd();


            auto r = runc.glOut->GetRawData();
            memset(r, 0, wi2 * he2 * 4);
            glReadPixels(0, 0, wi2, he2, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, r);
            glfwSwapBuffers(win);
            SetEvent(hRun2);
        }
        else { ... }
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    win = 0;
    hOpenGL = 0;
    SetEvent(hRun2);
}
```

Is there a way to have a window rendering larger than the current screen size? Even in software rendering.

Comment: Where do you call `glViewport`?

Comment: @BDL I tried adding it, same result (code edited).

Comment: If nothing else works, then I recommend using a Frambuffer Object (because that's not bound to a window).

Comment: "it renders to a portion of the window" [Pixel ownership test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Per-Sample_Processing#Pixel_ownership_test)